# Unable to add objects to NSMutableArray in for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to add dictionary keys to objects in an array and then add them to a final array here:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newVen = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray *final = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *obj in self.venues) {
    [newVen setObject:[obj valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
    [final addObject:newVen];
}
```

The problem is it only adds the same 'name' to the final array and when I print out, let's say after 3 loops I get:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x79e26990>(
{
    name = Mustang;
},
{
    name = Mustang;
},
{
    name = Mustang;
}
)
```

I'm expecting an array of different names, e.g. Mustang, Ferarri, BMW

Comment: So, why are you adding the same object 3 times, vs 3 different objects?

Comment: And did you even want to add dictionaries at all, vs just adding the strings directly?

Comment: The self.venues has 3 objects that make it loop 3 times. There are dictionary keys from other arrays I'm also planning to add to objects in the final array.

Comment: You insert the same `newVen` object 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are adding the same mutabledict three times, the first time with the name of the first object, the second with the name of the second mutating both the first and the second, ant the third you are mutating all because all are the same mutableDict. 
I think you might not need a mutable dict inside, you can use this:

```
  NSMutableArray *final = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *obj in self.venues) {
NSDictionary *newVen =@{@"name":[obj valueForKey:@"name"]};
[final addObject:newVen];
}
```

If you need your dict inside the array will be mutable use this:

```
      NSMutableArray *final = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *obj in self.venues) {
NSMutableDictionary *newVen =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"name":[obj valueForKey:@"name"]}];
[final addObject:newVen];
}
```